# w3wp process only show ids not names

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis

I am trying to attach to a process on Visual Studio but I only see some Ids instead of the name of the process.

I checked other w3wp questions but they just have solution for not seeing any processes. My problem is my process is right there but I can't see which is mine because there are 4 processes of w3wp and I can't see the names of the websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a similar issue. I have tried to hit my web page first and then check the name of your process again. In my case this solution didn't work instantly. ids were still there. So I opened Task Manager () and checked all w3wp processes from Details tab and get the exact Ids of websites according to their names. I was able to attach the related service with Ids and once I restart IIS and my websites I also saw the names of my websites again.

Comment: Running VS as administrator helped my case.